# Group By Operator Not Behaving as Expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT groupname, 
       Result = CASE 
                  WHEN ( thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form IS NULL 
                          OR thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form = '' ) THEN 
                  thd_requesttypeidmform
                  ELSE thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form 
                END 
FROM   zendeskticketexport 
WHERE  (groupname = 'DC Maintenance') 
        AND thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form = 'attribute_update_requests__discontinue___obsolete_request'
GROUP  BY groupname, 
          thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form, 
          thd_requesttypeidmform 
ORDER  BY groupname
```

The result I am receiving:

```
groupname       Result

DC Maintenance  attribute_update_requests__discontinue___obsolete_request
DC Maintenance  attribute_update_requests__discontinue___obsolete_request
DC Maintenance  attribute_update_requests__discontinue___obsolete_request
```

What's throwing me off is the result; I believe the group by operator should group identical records together, but something with the group by operator in conjuction with the case operator is causing these records not to group. In testing the two cases, I see the following query is returning 0 records:

```
select * from ZendeskTicketExport 

where groupName = 'DC Maintenance' and thd_requesttypeidmform = 'attribute_update_requests__discontinue___obsolete_request'
```

In my mind this would indicate that all of the records should group together, since the case operator is only returning values for the thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form  field. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why can't you remove order and make it as Derived table and then Group by

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this query. Your `AND thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form = ...` pretty much excludes all of your `CASE` expression.

Comment: Why are you doing a GROUP BY? I can't see the purpose here... Are you just trying to do `SELECT DISTINCT` in a complex way?

Comment: To answer the last two questions, this is not ultimately the query I wanted to make. The purpose of the query shown is to break the problem down enough to make it more answerable here on Stack Overflow...next time I post I'll include the larger query if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're grouping by a third column. SQL Server will create your groups, even if that column itself isn't in the `SELECT`.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT groupname, 
       CASE
           WHEN (thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form IS NULL OR
                 thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form = '' ) THEN thd_requesttypeidmform
           ELSE thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form 
       END
FROM   zendeskticketexport 
WHERE
    groupname = 'DC Maintenance' AND
    thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form = 'attribute_update_requests__discontinue___obsolete_request'
GROUP  BY groupname,
          thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form,
       CASE
           WHEN (thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form IS NULL OR
                 thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form = '' ) THEN thd_requesttypeidmform
           ELSE thd_requesttype_dca_oms_form 
       END
ORDER  BY groupname
```

Comment: Thanks! Added a case operator to my group by as well and this resolved the issue.